# Python List comprehension with conditional iteration

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Just want to ask if this particular set of code can be expressed into a one-liner list comprehension:

```
files = ["country_Maldives", "country_East Timor", "country_Laos", "country_Uruguay"]
accountlist = ["Laos", "Maldives"]

final_list = []
for account in accountlist:
    included = [file for file in files if account in file][0]
    final_list.append(included)
```

Thank you.

Comment: final_list = [file for account in accountlist for file in files if account in file ]

Comment: Almost certainly, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `any/all` operators:

```
ret = [file for file in files if any(account in file for account in accountlist)]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any

UDP

Oneliner above returns list of ALL files each of which contains ANY of accounts. If you want to find only first entries by given condition, operator `next` is also worth mentioning:

```
ret = [next((file for file in files if account in file), []) for account in accountlist]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next

Answer (score 2):

Since your code just fetches all the matches and picks the first one with:

```
[file for file in files if account in file][0]
```

You could instead use  [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to keep retrieving the next item until a match is found:

```
result = [next(file for file in files if account in file) for account in accountlist]

print(result)
# ['country_Laos', 'country_Maldives'] => Same output as your original code
```

The only problem with the above is that a [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) exception will be raised if the iterator is exhausted and no match has been found. To prevent this, we can supply a default value instead, such as `None`, so it returns this value instead of the exception.

```
[next((file for file in files if account in file), None) for account in accountlist]
```

Then if we wanted to filter out `None` matches, we could use another list comprehension to do that:

```
filtered = [file for file in result if file is not None]
```

Answer (score 0):

just another way, nesting the for loops...

```
In [19]: files = ["country_Maldives", "country_East Timor", "country_Laos", "country_Uruguay"]
    ...: accountlist = ["Laos", "Maldives"]

In [20]: res=[file  for acc in accountlist for file in files  if acc in file.split('_')]

In [21]: res
Out[21]: ['country_Laos', 'country_Maldives']
```

Comment: This is absolutely incorrect. What if `files = ["country_Maldives", "country_East Timor", "country_Laos", "country_2_Laos", "country_Uruguay"]`?

Comment: @Booboo,I have updated the answer now. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: I still get `['country_Laos', 'country_2_Laos', 'country_Maldives']` with my input.

Comment: @Booboo, yes that's what is expected . As Laos is present, so it should be returned. right ?

Comment: **Run my input against the OP's code using my value for the variable `files`**. Notice that the OP is selecting element 0 of all the matches, i.e. the first match only in the country list for each item in the account list. Look at @RoadRunner's answer, especially his description about using `next` to get the first match.